# Let m be the smallest number among: $(x-y)^2, (y-z)^2, (z-x)^2$ Prove $m \le \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let m be the smallest number among: $(x-y)^2, (y-z)^2, (z-x)^2$

Prove $m \le \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

My attempts: $3m \le (x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2$ so I tried to prove $(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2 \le \frac{3}{2}(x^2+y^2+z^2) \rightarrow 4(xy+yz+zx)\le x^2+y^2+z^2$ but it wrong

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you

Comment: FYI the inequality $(x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2 \leq \frac{3}{2}(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$ does not hold in general. For instance, consider $x=2, y=-1, z=-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wlog assume that $x\ge y \ge z $ , then  $m=min\{(x-y)^2, (y-z)^2\} \le (x-y)(y-z)$

Note that

$$x^2+y^2+z^2-2(x-y)(y-z)=(x-y+z)^2+2y^2 \ge 0$$

Hence

$$x^2+y^2+z^2 \ge 2(x-y)(y-z) \ge 2m$$

Equality holds when $y=0, x=-z$

Comment: +1. Small nitpick: Note that we're implicitly using that $x-y, y-z \geq 0$ here. If this were not true, we would not have $(x-y)(y-z) \geq m$.

Comment: Thank you Alex g

Comment: Thanh you so muchh